# Python not reading/writing entire csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a project where I have to parse a huge csv file with 500,000 rows. Below is a small portion of code as an example. It breaks up the columns fine, but it only reads 9,132 rows when I need it to go through all 500,000. The csv is encoded in cp1252, which I have a feeling might be part of the issue but I am not sure. Also here is the error I am getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4123: character maps to <undefined>
```

Code:

```
import csv

outfile = open("newFile.csv", 'w')
with open("ProductFile.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        Item_ID = row[0]
        Sku = row[1]
        SKU_ID = row[2]
        altpartnum = row[3]
        Application = row[4]
        Brandcode = row[5]

        line = "{},{},{},{},{},{},\n".format(
            Item_ID, AD_SKU_ID, MemberSku, Application, Brandcode, Application, Brandcode)
        outfile.write(line)
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: I would recomend using pandas

Comment: What’s the complete error message?  Specify the correct encoding in the open call. The default might not be what you think. Why aren’t you using csv.writer for the output file?

Comment: If the file is `cp1252`, tell `open` that, `open("ProductFile.csv", encoding='cp1252', newline='')` (the `"r"` is unnecessary, being the default, and the `newline=''` is required by the `csv` module so it untranslated newlines and can parse them according to the dialect rules properly).

Comment: On top of Mark suggestion to use `csv.writer` for the output file, it's extra important to use `with` statements with output files too; otherwise exceptions don't close the file reliably. You can open both files on the same line (read first, so you don't blow away the output file until you know the input file exists): `with open("ProductFile.csv",  encoding='cp1252', newline='') as f, open("newFile.csv", 'w') as outfile:` works, and you can then remove `outfile.close()`, no need to change indentation levels.

Comment: Oh, and lastly, those six lines of row extractions can be removed, changing the `for` loop to `for Item_ID, Sku, SKU_ID, altpartnum, Application, Brandcode in reader:` (if there are more than six columns in the input, `for Item_ID, Sku, SKU_ID, altpartnum, Application, Brandcode, *_ in reader:` will ignore the remaining columns), dramatically simplifying things.

Comment: byte 0x81 isn't decodable by `cp1252` so the file isn't actually encoded in `cp1252`.  It might be `ISO-8859-1` (aka `latin1`), but that encoding will decode anything so you may get mojibake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CP1252 doesn't support decoding byte 0x81, so the encoding is not CP1252.  It might be ISO-88591 (a.k.a latin1) but it will encoded all bytes to *something* so you may get [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

Suggested code (but use the correct encoding if not `latin1`):

```py
import csv

with (open('ProductFile.csv', 'r', encoding='latin1', newline='') as fin,
      open('newFile.csv', 'w', encoding='latin1', newline='') as fout):

    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row[:6]) # first 6 columns or whatever you want to write
                               # The OP code had undefined variables
```